# ROS: Binding a callback function and a object member to a subscriber node

Tags: c++, static, callback, ros

I'm writing a class with the goal to provide a model to rviz. The class shall be able to subscribe a topic to simulate some movements. Therefore I want to use `node.subscribe` but the problem is, that `subscribe` expects a `static void` function. That means I have no access to my class members and methods.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Here the shortened code:

*MyClass.h*

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        tf::Transform transform;
        ros::Subscriber subscriber;

    public:
        int publish ();

    private:
        static void callback ( std_msgs::Float64MultiArray msg);
};
```

*MyClass.cpp*

```
MyClass::MyClass( )
{
    this->subscriber =
      this->node.subscribe( "topic_id",
                            1,
                            &MyClass::callback,
                            this->transform);
}

void MyClass::callback( std_msgs::Float64MultiArray msg, tf::Transform &transform)
{
    std::vector<double> data(4);
    data = msg.data;

    transform->setRotation( tf::Quaternion(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]) );
    publish ();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to ROS wiki, there's no such need for a static void. 
I quote this as a reference from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers):

> callback
>
> Depending on the version of subscribe() you're using, this may be any
>   of a few things. The most common is a class method pointer and a
>   pointer to the instance of the class. This is explained in more detail
>   later.

Thus, just declare your callback as a **class method pointer** without the static qualifier and it should work just fine.

Another point is that it would be better to `use boost::bind if you callback will need some arguments` in the subscriber description. (see this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/12045/how-to-deliver-arguments-to-a-callback-function/)). But, that's not needed here since you can access your private attribute `transform` inside the class method `callback`.

Here's the corrected header code (as obvious as it might be), with adding the `node::handler` because I don't really know what your `node` is :

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        ros::NodeHandle ph_;
        tf::Transform transform;
        ros::Subscriber subscriber;

    public:
        int publish ();

    private:
        void callback (const std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::ConstPtr& msg);
};
```

and cpp file :

```
MyClass::MyClass( ) : ph_("~")
{
    subscriber = ph_.subscribe( "topic_id",
                            1,
                            &MyClass::callback,
                            this);
}

void MyClass::callback(const std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::vector<double> data(4);
    data = msg.data;

    transform->setRotation( tf::Quaternion(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]) );
    publish ();
}
```

Cheers,